# Carregar texto do select no input

Tags: javascript

Oi eu preciso de ajuda com esse código, quero que o input seja carregado quando o select alterar o valor. Mas não posso mudar nada no select, porque é uma adaptação que estou fazendo no Prestashop.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TESTE</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getHTML() {
      var vai = $('#testID option:selected').html();
      alert(vai);
    }
  </script>

  <input id="vai" name="vai" value="" onClick="getHTML(select,textfield)">

  <select id="testID">
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">Value3</option>
    <option value="4">Value4</option>
    <option value="5">Value5</option>
    <option value="6">Value6</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="Get dropdown selected Value" onClick="getHTML();">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o script depois do HTML e podes fazer isso com:

```
$('#testID').change(function() {
    $('#vai').val(this.value);
});
```

Exemplo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TESTE</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <input id="vai" name="vai" value="" onClick="getHTML(select,textfield)">

  <select id="testID">
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">Value3</option>
    <option value="4">Value4</option>
    <option value="5">Value5</option>
    <option value="6">Value6</option>
  </select>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#testID').change(function() {
    $('#vai').val(this.value);
  });
</script>

</html>
```